# Plotting a cluster with [1*n] matrix variable

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am a beginner when it comes to R. I am trying to plot the clusters (after estimating them, of course) of my data set (2 variables). I used

```
kmeans(x, centers, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1,
       algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy",
                     "MacQueen"), trace=FALSE)
## S3 method for class 'kmeans'
fitted(object, method = c("centers", "classes"), ...)
```

[Cluster Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN6JN.png)

And got to this point, but I am quite unsure how I should proceed in order to get a graph showing one variable on the x and the other on the y axis with clusters indicated.

How should I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to save the object into a variable and then plot it?

y<-kmeans(x,center,....)
plot(y)

Comment: No. What command should I use?

Comment: Just plot(your object) might do, if they implemented a plot method. I will try it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this what you should do:

```
result<-kmeans(x,centers,...)

plot(data$x,data$y, col=result$cluster)
```

that will just plot the data and color respective observation depending what cluster it is. 
Then you can add the center of clusters

```
points(result$clusters, col=1:2, pch=18,cex=2)
```

the last two commands pch and cex are just what the center points will look like.

Comment: Works! Thanks.

One more thing: how can check the size of my clusters and how to reconcile it to the graph?

Comment: you mean how many elements in each cluster? I think basic overview: table(result$cluster) that will say how many of each class there are. if you want proportional: prop.table(table(result$cluster)).

If you're happy with answer, please accept it by ticking on the left. thanks :)